# Django MultipleObjectsReturned error on form submit

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset, modelform, modelchoicefield

I've got quite the mysterious MultipleObjectsReturned error that just popped up after weeks of not having an issue. I'm hoping is just something simple that I'm missing.

I've got an `Order` model, an `OrderLine` model, which has an `Item` foreign key. Each `Item` has a foreign key to a `Product`. Here are the dumbed down models:

```
class OrderLine(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name="lines", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)


class Product(TimeStampedModel):
   ...


class Item(TimeStampedModel):
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

OrderLineForm and OrderLineAdmin for reference:

```
class OrderLineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderLine
        ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].queryset = ItemType.objects.all()
        self.fields['product'].queryset = Product.objects.none()
        self.fields['item'].queryset = Item.objects.none()

        if self.instance.pk:
            try: # When changing an existing OrderLine
                ...
                current_item = Item.objects.filter(pk=self.instance.item.pk)
                available_items = current_item.union(
                    get_available_items(...)
                )
                self.fields['item'].queryset = available_items
                self.fields['category'].initial = item_type_id
            except:
                self.fields['item'].queryset = Item.objects.all()
        ...


@admin.register(OrderLine)
class OrderLineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = OrderLineForm
```

Now, when I use Django admin to edit an `OrderLine` which has **more than one** `Item` in the ModelChoiceField queryset:
[image]

I get the following error during form clean: `get() returned more than one Item -- it returned 2!`

Upon closer inspection of the logs, it appears the `ModelChoiceField` is getting passed the correct `Item` id/pk, but the `self.queryset.get(**{key:value})` is somehow returning 2 Items from a single id/pk, even though the Items have different id/pks (49 and 50):
[image]

**Again, this only happens when the `OrderLine` form's `Item` field has more than one object in the queryset. If it's only a single `Item`, it saves just fine. Any ideas why I'm getting this error now? Thanks!**

The only thing I can think has changed in terms of database relationhips is that I added `formset.save_m2m()` to the Item model admin, however Item isn't a m2m relationship, so perhaps that could have led to some database indexing error?

P.S. I found this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23354 from years ago that seems to reference the error in this context, but the ticket said it was fixed.

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by "_OrderLine which has more than one Item in the ModelChoiceField queryset_"? Can you show your ModelAdmin?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat sorry didn't know how to word that succinctly. I've added the `OrderLineForm` to the question, which `OrderLineAdmin` uses. Upon OrderLineForm init, the currently selected `Item` and any other available items are provided as the `self.fields['item'].queryset`. So the form queryset can have either 1 or more `Items` in it, and it's currently giving the error when more than one `Item` is in this queryset

Comment: I see you call `union` on the queryset there. Do note that according to the documentation only specific methods can be called on the resulting queryset (`get` is not one of those). Is there no way to do this without `union`? Can you show what `get_available_items` does exactly?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat That was it!!! Thank you so much. `get_available_items` returns a QuerySet of `Items`. Since the `Item` of the current `OrderLine` being edited doesn't exist in this queryset, I decided to use `union` to combine `current_item` with `available items`. When I removed the union, it worked flawlessly. So is there a standard way to combine QuerySets without using `union`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From these two lines we can see that you perform a union and set this as the fields queryset:

```
current_item = Item.objects.filter(pk=self.instance.item.pk)
available_items = current_item.union(
    get_available_items(...)
)
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#union) on `union`:

> In addition, only **LIMIT**, **OFFSET**, **COUNT(*)**, **ORDER BY**,
> and specifying columns (i.e. slicing, **count()**, **exists()**,
> **order_by()**, and **values()**/**values_list()**) are allowed on the resulting **QuerySet**. Further, databases place restrictions on what
> operations are allowed in the combined queries. For example, most
> databases don’t allow **LIMIT** or **OFFSET** in the combined queries.

Considering that the field will call `get` on this queryset to validate the selected choice a union is not feasible for it. Considering your use case in fact there is a better option of us just using the SQL **OR** operator. There are mainly 2 ways to do this:

1. Use the [`|` operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#or):

   ```
    available_items = current_item | get_available_items(...)
   ```

   This is equivalent to saying `SELECT ... WHERE (condition for current item) OR (conditions for available items)`.
2. Use [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

   The previous method was not very great considering we may want to make queries having quite complex conditions. This would result in us writing a bunch of querysets and then using `|` and `&` on them. Rather than doing this we have the great option of using `Q` objects which can take as keyword arguments the same arguments you would have passed to filter:

   ```
    from django.db.models import Q


    available_items = Item.objects.filter(Q(pk=self.instance.item.pk) | Q(some_condition_for_available=True))
   ```